# Why do my tf-idf values not appear consistent?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a series of tweets that I've converted to tokens. Among them are the following:

- geraldkutney happen realize happen conveniently rename catch yet emergency post fact come government
- michaelemann burn happen chickenshittily change get make stupid argument good deed go unpunished
- rickcaughell thomas_6278 coderedearth jrockstrom jordanbpeterson fact exxon predict good accuracy would happen temperature today back 1970s 80 prof model accurate

Note that the first two tweets have 13 total tokens and the  third one has three.

Using the following code, I have created TF-IDF values:

```
vectoriser = sk_text.TfidfVectorizer()

vectoriser.fit(twit_api['text_clean'])

twit_vec = vectoriser.transform(twit_api['text_clean'])
twit_vec.columns = vectoriser.get_feature_names_out()

tokens_enc = twit_vec.toarray()
```

When I look at the tf-idf values for the word 'happen' in each of these, I get values
`0.41124561276932653`, `0.18906439908376366` and `0.1523571031416618`.

This is with the code

```
print(tokens_enc[row_nos[0], vectoriser.vocabulary_['happen']])
```

These values don't appear consistent to me. I would expect the first value to be equal to double the second one as the  tf is exactly double however this doesn't appear to be the case.

Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many parameters that can be used with your tfidf function and the ones you don't specify have default values. In your case the three parameters that are affecting you are

```
# ---------------------------
norm{‘l1’, ‘l2’} or None, default=’l2’
Each output row will have unit norm, either:

‘l2’: Sum of squares of vector elements is 1. The cosine similarity between two vectors is their dot product when l2 norm has been applied.

‘l1’: Sum of absolute values of vector elements is 1. See normalize.

None: No normalization.

# ---------------------------
use_idfbool, default=True
Enable inverse-document-frequency reweighting. If False, idf(t) = 1.

# ---------------------------
smooth_idfbool, default=True
Smooth idf weights by adding one to document frequencies, as if an extra document was seen containing every term in the collection exactly once. Prevents zero divisions.
```

There is smoothing and normalization happening behind the scenes but it looks like you can turn all of those off. Try something like the following

```
vectoriser = sk_text.TfidfVectorizer(norm=None, use_idfbool=False, smooth_idfbool=False)
```

Without your dataset, I cannot test this but referring back to the [function documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) for these parameters will be helpful for any further issues.

Comment: The IDF configuration shouldn't affect the ratios of TF-IDF scores for the same token between documents. Normalization is the answer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `TfidfVectorizer` uses `norm=l2`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html this means that every row will be scaled down using something like `row /= np.sum(np.dot(row, row))`.

This default setting is so that the dot product of any two TF-IDF vectors results in a valid cosine similarity, which otherwise would require an additional scaling operation. However, the downside is that TF-IDF values are no longer directly comparable across documents. Ratios within each row will be preserved by this scaling operation, but ratios between rows will be broken.

Example:

```py
import warnings
from typing import TypeVar

import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer


T = TypeVar("T")

def identity(x: T) -> T:
    return x

docs = [
    ["cat", "hat", "bat", "hat"],
    ["hat", "mat", "sat", "sat", "sat", "mat"],
]

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=identity, preprocessor=identity)
tfidf_transformer_l2 = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf_transformer_none = TfidfTransformer(norm=None)

# Ignore warning about unused parameters in CountVectorizer
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        "ignore",
        category=UserWarning,
        module=r"^sklearn.*",
        message=r".*token_pattern.*",
    )
    docs_counts = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

docs_tfidf_none = tfidf_transformer_none.fit_transform(docs_counts)
docs_tfidf_l2 = tfidf_transformer_l2.fit_transform(docs_counts)

print("Counts:")
print(docs_counts.A)
print()

print("TF-IDF, unnormalized:")
print(docs_tfidf_none.A)
print()

print("TF-IDF, L2-normalized:")
print(docs_tfidf_l2.A)
print()

# Applying L2 normalization manually
print("TF-IDF, L2-normalized (manually):")
print((docs_tfidf_none / np.linalg.norm(docs_tfidf_none.A, axis=1)[:, None]).A)
print()

# 2:1 ratio is preserved
print("Count ratio of token 2:", docs_counts[0,2] / docs_counts[1,2])
print("TF-IDF ratio, unnormalized:", docs_tfidf_none[0,2] / docs_tfidf_none[1,2])

# 2:1 ratio is broken
print("TF-IDF ratio, L2-normalized:", docs_tfidf_l2[0,2] / docs_tfidf_l2[1,2])
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered setting a constant seed before running any vectorization. Something like `np.random.seed(22)`

Comment: There should not be any randomization in this vectorizer.

Comment: @Anudey this would be a comment post instead of an answer post.